# Moving between instances of class like Num

Tags: haskell

The following might contain a stupid question but since I am somewhat new to Haskell I think I am in the clear. :)

I haven't got the faintest of how to express my question in valid Haskell lingo, but I think I can express it in English!

---

I my current state of naivety I believe there is some secret recipe that allows you to move between instance of a class, like instance of Num..

For example:

```
class Language l where
    add     :: Int -> Int -> l
    jmp     :: Int -> l
    noop    :: l

data Assembler where
    Add     :: Int -> Int -> Assembler
    Jmp     :: Int -> Assembler
    Noop    :: Assembler

instance Language Assembler where
    add = Add
    jmp = Jmp
    noop = Noop

data C where
    Plus    :: Int -> Int -> C
    Goto    :: Int -> C
    Void0   :: C

instance Language C where
    add     = Plus
    jmp     = Goto
    noop    = Void0

example :: C
example = add 1 2
```

Without changing the type of example how could I transform it to Assembler, I could write a function :: C -> Assembler, but that is not my question, rather I would like to ask if I could leverage the class/instance things instead to attain the same behaviour? Is there something here or I am I just buggering about?

Comment: Just modify `example :: C` to `example :: Language a => a` and you are good to go

Comment: Haha, yes indeed, updated my question.

Comment: So, you want `function :: (Language a, Language b) => a -> b`? This is an odd use of classes to start with, resembling an attempt to model OOP classes. A typeclass usually has "laws" associated with it, governing how the things defined in the class should interoperate with each other or other things. Also, it's not clear what, for instance, what `Add :: Int -> Int -> Assembler` is supposed to represent.

Comment: It is very likely that I abuse/wrongfully use the concepts in Haskell, but that is my mission now, learning these concepts, so I'm thankful for your feedback. 

C and Assembler etc, is supposed to represent DSL:s, so  Add is a syntax of that DSL, as of yet I think of that syntax as a kind of rule.

Comment: Ah, ok. Typically, both `Assembler, C :: Type -> Type`, and are often instances of `Functor`. A "program" in the language is usually then written in monad style, like `Add x y >> Add y z >> Noop >> Jmp n`. How you produce the monad necessary to use each language varies; options include type-specific `Monad` instances, free monads generated from a functor, or freer monads generated from a possibly non-functor type with kind `Type -> Type`. `Language` would probably just have a single method `eval` that takes a value of type `Language l => l` and produces a result.

Comment: Hum, I understand the recipe and it is very useful, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about "some secret recipe that allows you to move between instance of a class, like instances of `Num`", you've perhaps gotten this impression by observing the behavior of numeric literals, and seeing that you can write:

```
> 2 :: Int
2
> 2 :: Integer
2
> 2 :: Double
2.0
> 2 :: Float
2.0
```

Here, it looks as if the integer `2` is allowed to "change types" between multiple instances of `Num`, right?  So, why can't we do something similar with `example`?

```
> example :: C
Plus 1 2
> example :: Assembler
<interactive>:14:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Assembler’ with actual type ‘C’
    • In the expression: example :: Assembler
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = example :: Assembler
```

Well, the reason has to do with the actual type of numeric literals.  If we ask GHCi for the type of `2`:

```
> :t 2
2 :: Num p => p
```

we see that the expression `2` doesn't actually have a specific (i.e., "monomorphic") integer type.  Instead, `2` has a polymorphic type, `Num p => p` which can be thought of as "any type you like, as long as it has a `Num` instance".  So, it's not that `2` is "changing types" in the above example.  Rather, the type of `2` is being **specialized** from the polymorphic type `Num p => p` to a specific monomorphic type like `Int` or `Double`, depending on where it's used, in much the same way that the addition operator `+` can be specialized from its polymorphic type of:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

to any of:

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
(+) :: Double -> Double -> Double
etc.
```

when it's used in different contexts.

Getting back to your example, I think you were pretty quick to dismiss @boran's comment as some dirty trick that missed the point of your question.  But, in fact, his comment is the **answer** to your question.  The sort of "movement between instances of a class" that you're thinking of is accomplished by defining polymorphic expressions with type class constraints and then *specializing* to the desired instance.

Just as `2 :: Num p => p` can be specialized to any `Num` instance, the polymorphic version of `example'`:

```
example' :: Language l => l
example' = add 1 2
```

can be specialized to any `Language` instance:

```
> example' :: C
Plus 1 2
it :: C
> example' :: Assembler
Add 1 2
it :: Assembler
```

There's a whole [paper about writing "tagless final" interpreters](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf) using this technique, and it's definitely worth reading.

Anyway, it's this specialization process that provides apparent movement between class instances.  There's no other general, automatic mechanism for converting between arbitrary type class instances.

Comment: I now feel I am closer to the light.. which always seems like a temporary state when dealing with Haskell. May thanks.

Comment: The paper you forwarded is spott on.